# Azure Logic Apps internal server error 500

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Am trying to create a an azure function that is triggered in a Logic Apps, 
The functions purpose is to web crawl certain web sites, take the desired information, compare that with a a SQL Server database in Azure, compare if we already have that information if not add it.

My issue is that when ever i run it I get the Server 500 error, I assume its  accessing the database that cause. Help?

```
   public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log
            )
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");


            string RequestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();


            {
                return await CrawlBlog(0, RequestBody);
            }

        }



        private static async Task<IActionResult> CrawlBlog(int Picker, string req)
        {

            int BlogPicker = Picker;

            string TheResult = req;
            //Get the url we want to test
            var Url = "";
            if (BlogPicker == 0)
            {
                Url = "*********";
            }
            else if (BlogPicker == 1)
            {
                Url = "*********";
            }
            /*
            else if (BlogPicker == 2)
            {
                Url = "https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/?utm_source=devglan";
            }
            */
            else
            {
                TheResult = "False we got a wrong pick";
                return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult
                    ( new {TheResult });
                    }

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var html =  await httpClient.GetStringAsync(Url);
            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();

            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);


            //a list to add all availabel blogs we found
            var Blog = new List<BlogStats>();

            switch (BlogPicker)
            {
                case 0:
                    {
                        var divs =
                        htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("home_blog_sec_text")).ToList();



                        foreach (var divo in divs)
                        {
                            var Blogo = new BlogStats
                            {

                                Summary = divo.Descendants("p").FirstOrDefault().InnerText,

                                Link = divo.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault().ChildAttributes("href").FirstOrDefault().Value,

                                Title = divo.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault().InnerText
                            };

                            Blog.Add(Blogo);


                        }

                        break;
                    }

                case 1:
                    {
                        var divs =
                        htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("post_header_title two_third last")).ToList();

                        foreach (var divo in divs)
                        {
                            //string TheSummary = "we goofed";

                            var ThePs = divo.Descendants("p").ToList();


                            var Blogo = new BlogStats
                            {


                                Summary = ThePs[1].GetDirectInnerText(),


                                Link = divo.Descendants("a").LastOrDefault().ChildAttributes("href").FirstOrDefault().Value,

                                Title = divo.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault().InnerText

                            };

                            Blog.Add(Blogo);


                        }

                        break;
                    }


            }



            TheResult = await SqlCheck(Blog[0].Title, Blog[0].Summary, Blog[0].Link); //error 500


            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult
            (
                new
                {
                    TheResult
                }
                );

        }

        public static async Task<string> SqlCheck(string Tit, string Sumy, string Lin)
        {

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.DataSource = "flygon.database.windows.net";
            builder.UserID = "*****";
            builder.Password = "********";
            builder.InitialCatalog = "torkoal";

            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);

            connection.Open();



            SqlCommand CheckCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableBoto WHERE  Link = @id3 ", connection);

            CheckCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id3", Lin);

            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(CheckCommand);



            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);

            int i = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;


            if (i > 0)
            {


                return $" We got a Duplicates in title : {Tit}";
            }



            try
            {

                {



                    string query = $"insert into TableBoto(Title,Summary,Link) values('{Tit}','{Sumy}','{Lin}');";

                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);



                    SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();



                    reader.Close();
                }
            }

            catch (SqlException)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }


            connection.Close();



            return $" Success Ign +{Tit} + Ign {Sumy}+ Ign {Lin} Ign Success SQL ";

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please try log analytics https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics

Answer (score 0):

500 HTTP status code is a generic code which means that the server was not able to process the request due to some issues, First step would be to add some exception handling to your function and see if the failure occurs and where it occurs.

On Side note, you should not use HTTP client in the way used in the code, you should not new it up every time your function executes, this client should be static in nature. Refer [Manage connections in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections)